# Windows 10 RE - kernel is missing or contains errors

Tags: windows-10, kernel, recovery, ntoskrnl.exe, windows-re

I was attempting to create a Veeam Recovery Media (a rescue disk for a backup app) today. Although it was created, it is unbootable, due to a problem with Windows RE, that is used to run this bootable disk. Later, I created a new USB Windows Rescue Disk from a scratch with my Windows 10, to check if the problem persists. Unfortunately, it doesn't work indeed. The symptoms are the same: the Windows RE disc can not be launched. While booting from a rescue disc, I received BSoD saying that the operating system couldn't be loaded because the kernel is missing or contains errors.

File: \windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
Error code: 0xc000a004

I want to underline that the computer works fine so far, and I don't see any distressing symptoms. Windows boots each time normally.

I will appreciate any help in resolving the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though I've never used that tool before, there are a plethora of free reputable Windows recovery tools using Windows RE, such as [Macrium Reflect Rescue Environment](https://blog.macrium.com/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61), [EaseUS Rescue Media](https://www.easeus.com/backup-recovery/how-to-boot-from-rescue-media.html), [Hiren's BootCD PE x64](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/).

During the creation of the [Windows RE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference?view=windows-11) recovery media, a [WIM](https://www.minitool.com/news/windows-recovery-environment-winre-wim.html) file containing all the "innards" of Windows RE is constructed. Evidently, *Veeam Recovery Media* is not building that WIM correctly. Rather than trying to troubleshoot that application, just use another Win RE builder. For example, *Macrium Reflect* downloads *all* needed files to build the WIM at the time the media is created, if the WIM has not been built before, or if you wish to change it.

[image: Build WIM in Macrium Reflect]

Note that the default base WIM is downloaded from Microsoft's *Windows Kits*, if not already present.

Comment: Obviously, I wasn't precise enough. I don't blame Veeam Recovery Media for the problem. WIndows Rescue Disc applet wasn't able to create properly working Windows RE USB stick either. According to what you said, maybe Windows is not building WIM correctly?

Comment: @gordom, I've never had an issue letting one of those mentioned apps first *build* the WIM, with little or no user input, and then put it on USB. See the image added above.

Comment: @gordom - You should the problem is with **their** WinRE image not your systems WinRE.

Comment: @Ramhound But as I said, if I create WinRE using Windows system Rescue Disc applet (without involving any Veeam tools), it doesn't work either. How to explain that?

Comment: I do have another WinRE USB stick that was created more than a 1 year ago. It works fine. Can I use it somehow to fix the problem?

Comment: @gordom - “Can I use it somehow to fix the problem?” - Fix your Veeam WinPE? No, you can’t